# not working Passing instance of class by reference in qt c++ lambda Signal&Slots

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

This code in Profile3.cpp i just want to pass the instance kitchenData of Kitchen_Data class reference not by value but it prints that

> error: undefined reference to
> `Profile3::Kitchen_DoubleClicked(Kitchen_Data&)'

```
Profile3::Profile3(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Profile3)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  Kitchen_Data  kitchenData;

  connect(ui->treeWidget_Kitchen,
        &QTreeWidget::itemDoubleClicked,
        [&,this]{Kitchen_DoubleClicked (kitchenData);});
}
```

in profile3.h i've the class

```
class Kitchen_Data{

public:

    QString MealCode;
    QString MealName;
    QString MealPrice;
    QString MealType;
    QTreeWidgetItem * itemm_CancelButton_From_Kitchen ;
    QVector <QString> KitechenItemPrice;
    QVector <QString> KitechenItemName;

    QString All_Added_ItemOfKitechen;
    QString KitchenTotalPrice;
};
```

and this private slots of profile3 class and the function that i want to use pass the instance to

```
private slots:


void  Kitchen_DoubleClicked(Kitchen_Data &Kitchen);
```

Comment: Also note that you pass a locally scoped variable `kitchenData` to your lambda by reference.  That will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan 
@G.M. 

Yes it's working atleast after i declared the function in cpp file `connect(ui->treeWidget_Kitchen, &QTreeWidget::itemDoubleClicked, [&,this](QTreeWidgetItem *item){Kitchen_DoubleClicked (item,Kitchen);});`

 But in the function when i use the instance the software crahes

`void Profile3::Kitchen_DoubleClicked(QTreeWidgetItem * item,Kitchen_Data &Kitchen) {
 itemList_Kitechen = ui->treeWidget_Kitchen->selectedItems();
 foreach( item, itemList_Kitechen){ Kitchen.MealCode = item->text(0);` 
for sure there are more

Comment: @G.M. @MuhammetAliAsan i edit the lambda code coz of the scope
` connect(ui->treeWidget_Kitchen, &QTreeWidget::itemDoubleClicked,             [&,this](QTreeWidgetItem *item){Kitchen_DoubleClicked (item, Kitchen_Data  Kitchen);}); `
i did this and prints an error `Kitchen_Data doesn't refer to a value` however i've the class in the Profile3.h so how to pass instance to the function without getting this time error .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, passing a reference to a local variable in the lambda is a bad idea. The instance `kitchenData` will already be out of scope/destroyed by the time you access it from within the `Kitchen_DoubleClicked` slot. To make it survive long enough to be used by the slot, you need to either dynamically allocate it (e.g. `Kitchen_Data* kitchenData = new Kitchen_Data;`), or make `kitchenData` a member of the `Profile3` class, e.g.:

```
class Profile3 {
    Kitchen_Data kitchenData;
    // other members, methods, slots, etc...
};
```

Comment: i made your instructions 
i got this error 
` uninitialized reference member in 'class Kitchen_Data&' [-fpermissive] `

and this the code

`class Profile3 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:


    explicit Profile3(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    Kitchen_Data &Kitchen;
// other stuff
private slots:
 void  Kitchen_DoubleClicked(QTreeWidgetItem *item,Kitchen_Data &Kitchen);
}`

Comment: so i changed to makethe argument in the constructor also got error and 
`class Profile3 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Profile3(QWidget *parent = nullptr, Kitchen_Data &Kitchen);}`

`Profile3::Profile3(QWidget *parent, Kitchen_Data &Kitchen) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Profile3)
{connect(ui->treeWidget_Kitchen,
            &QTreeWidget::itemDoubleClicked,
            [&,this](QTreeWidgetItem *item){Kitchen_DoubleClicked (item, Kitchen);});}`

Comment: the problem that i can't intitalize the instance by pointer that there is a price that should be updated and keep the past value of the price e.g add an item increase the price and delete it that deducted the price of this item and and i've another 4 treeWidget that passing will work for all of them so i've to use it , Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't declare `Kitchen` to be a reference; declare it like I did in my example code. I'm not quite sure how your program is supposed to work, but if you increase the total price when you add a new item, then can't you just decrease the price when you remove an item? Just store the price of each individual item so you know how much to deduct when you remove it.

Comment: Thanks it works, but may i ask why when i declared `Kitchen_Data &Kitchen` in the class itself didn't work ?

Comment: When you use that syntax (using the "&"), you're declaring that `Kitchen` is a reference to a `Kitchen_Data` instance. A reference is like an alias to some other variable, similar to a pointer. The rule in C++ is that you have to initialize a reference at the point where it is defined. A `Kitchen_Data` variable is NOT created automatically when you create the reference - you have to have one already instantiated. That's why your code failed to compile; you didn't initialize `Kitchen` in the class constructor. However, a reference is not what you want for your design anyway.